# Nested class, implemented interface object

Tags: java, class, interface, nested

I want to create an object `KalkulatorI.AccumulatorI` in a JUnit test case. When I create `Kalkulator.Accumulator` it's ok (`Kalkulator.Accumulator t2 = new Kalkulator().new Accumulator()`). How can I create such a interface object? I tried:

```
KalkulatorI.AccumulatorI t = new KalkulatorI.AccumulatorI();
```

or

```
KalkulatorI.AccumulatorI t = new KalkulatorI().new AccumulatorI();
```

but it doesn't work.

`AccumulatorI.java`:

```
public interface AccumulatorI {
    public int getValue();
    public void setValue(int acc);
}
```

`KalkulatorI.java`:

```
public interface KalkulatorI {
    public void setAccumulatorA(AccumulatorI a);
    public void setAccumulatorB(AccumulatorI a);
}
```

`Kalkulator.java`:

```
public class Kalkulator implements KalkulatorI {

    private AccumulatorI AA;
    private AccumulatorI BB;

    class Accumulator implements AccumulatorI{
        private int acc;

        public int getValue(){
            int res = this.acc;
            return res;
        }

        public void setValue(int acc){
            this.acc=acc;
        }
    }

    public void setAccumulatorA(AccumulatorI a){
        this.AA=a;
    }
    public void setAccumulatorB(AccumulatorI a){
        this.BB=a;
    }
}
```

Comment: `class Accumulator` is not a static property of Kalkulator. class Accumulartor instance can be created from Kalculator object. create it. and then create object of Accumulator.

Comment: KalkulatorI.AccumulatorI t = new KalkulatorI().new AccumulatorI()?

Comment: As said, you cannot instantiate Interface. But you can create anonymous class. I didn't get your question first. If at all you are trying to instantiate Accumulator not AccumulatorI, then create Kalculator object, say `kal`. create new object of Accumulator using `kal`. Regarding anonymous class, please google it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate interface so there is no way to call `new AccumulatorI()`. Please look at the [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)